# Additional prop in type does not throw error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Here is the sample code: First, I define:

```
type Option = { label: string, value: string}
```

Then I create some component `ExampleComponent` which contains prop `testProp: Option`

Then I use this component. When I do below it is incorrect and throw error which is expected:

```
<ExampleComponent
  testProp={{label: "", value: "", a: 1}}
/>
```

However, when I do below, no error is thrown out:

```
const foo = {label: "", value: "", a: 1}
<ExampleComponent
  testProp={foo}
/>
```

I did additional test, and if testProp is `testProp: () => Option`
Then below code is incorrect but not throw error which is not expected

```
<ExampleComponent
  testProp={() => {
     return {label: "", value: "", a: 1};
  }}
/>
```

Can someone explain this please?

Comment: Excess property checking is only applied when the object is _only_ accessible through the relevant interface. All of your values are structurally valid `Option`s.